# How to convert strings into lists

Tags: python

("1 34 23 12 -89 11)

How do I make it like this:

['1','34','23','12','-89','11']

This is spaced string which I need to convert to a list.

Comment: Use [split()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 2):

The `split` function can do this!

```
s = '1 34 23 12 -89 11'
l = s.split(' ') # ['1', '34', '23', '12', '-89', '11']
```

Comment: Nitpick: it's a function, not an operator.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Super-tiny nitpick: Its a method, not a function ;)

Comment: Haha, I deserve that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use split()

```
x="1 34 23 12 -89 11"
x.split()
```

output:

```
['1','34','23','12','-89','11']
```